# pdf from a dataset extracted from an excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dataset generated from reading an excel file. Is there a way to generate a pdf from the dataset without the use of any external dll's?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way of doing this but using iTextSharp is very easy, take a look http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/386996/How-to-export-datatable-to-PDF-using-Csharp-window